# Is there a way to inject into a hash in coffescript, just like in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript

In Ruby, i can do this:

```
hash = ['foo', 'bar'].each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i] = 0 }
```

How do I do the same in CoffeeScript, preferably using some elegant one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
hash = {}
hash[key] = 0 for key in ["foo", "bar"]
```

Also, in the Ruby example, you can use `each_with_object` instead of `inject` so that you don't need to return the `h` variable at the end:

```
hash = ['foo', 'bar'].each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i] = 0 }
```